# Geometric and algebraic multiplicities of $\alpha$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning, matrix-calculus

If $k$, $l$ and $n$ are integers such that $1 \leq k \leq l \leq n$, show that there exists an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and an eigenvalue $\alpha$ of $A$ such that $k$ and $l$ are the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of $\alpha$ with respect to $A$.

I figured out that the following matrix formation an algebraic multiplicity $l$ for $\alpha$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1       & 0 & \dots & 0& 0&\dots &0 \\
     0&\lambda_2        & \dots & 0& 0&\dots &0 \\
    .\\
    0  & 0  &\dots &\lambda_{n-k} & 0&\dots &0   \\
    0  & 0  &\dots &0 & \alpha&\dots &0   \\
.\\
    0  & 0  &\dots &0 & 0&\dots &\alpha   \\
\end{bmatrix}
but I need help regarding the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: Geometric multiplicity is the dimension of eigenspace generated

Comment: yes. but i cant figure out how to show that such a matrix exists. can you give me some hints?

Comment: You can try to calculate explicitly $\ker (\alpha I - A)$